# Python - How to take input from command line and pipe it into socket.gethostbyaddr("")

Tags: python, sockets, input, gethostbyaddr

I have been scouring the internet looking for the answer to this. Please not my python coding skills are not all that great. I am trying to create a command line script that will take the input from the command line like this:

```
$python GetHostID.py serverName.com
```

the last part is what I am wanting to pass on as a variable to socket.gethostbyaddr("") module. this is the code that I have so far. can someone help me figure out how to put that variable into the (" "). I think the "" is creating problems with using a simple variable name as it is trying to treat it as a string of text as appose to a variable name.
here is the code I have in my script:

```
#!/bin/python
# 
import sys, os
import optparse
import socket


remoteServer = input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
remoteServerIP  = socket.gethostbyaddr(remoteServer)
socket.gethostbyaddr('remoteServer')[0]
os.getenv('remoteServer')
print (remoteServerIP)
```

any help would be welcome. I have been racking my brain over this...
thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to put `remoteServer` in quotes at all?

Comment: when I do it with out the quotes it seems to error out. File "C:\Bin\Scripts\PyTools\tiniGetHost.py", line 10, in <module>
    socket.gethostbyaddr('remoteServer')[0]
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: i removed the quotes, it ran successfully in the python shell, but when i run it under the bash shell, it seems to not notice that i added the server name, and then errors out... ➤ python tiniGetHost.py serverName
Enter a remote host to scan: serverName    # had to take real name for posting.... #
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tiniGetHost.py", line 8, in <module>
    remoteServer = input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'serv' is not defined

Comment: I think you've tripped over one of the really nasty gotchas in the Python 2 standard library.  [You almost always want `raw_input`, not `input`.](https://www.smallsurething.com/the-difference-between-input-and-raw_input-in-python/) Or `sys.stdin.readline`.  Or, for this particular program, `sys.argv` is even better.

Comment: oh ok, ya in the direct python shell i am using 3.5.2, but in the MobaXterm version i am using 2.7 (i think...) that would explain why in the bash shell it is having a hard time running then.

Answer (score 1):

The command line arguments are available as the list `sys.argv`, whose first element is the path to the program. There are a number of libraries you can use (argparse, optparse, etc.) to analyse the command line, but for your simple application you could do something like this:

```
import sys
import sys, os
import optparse
import socket
remoteServer = sys.argv[1]
remoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyaddr(remoteServer)
print (remoteServerIP)
```

Running this program with the command line

```
$ python GetHostID.py holdenweb.com
```

gives the output

```
('web105.webfaction.com', [], ['108.59.9.144'])
```

Comment: awesome, thank you so much! i had another question related to this. for the socket module, is there a function that can be used to tell what remote OS the server is running? i am in a situation where i am running behind a heavely firewalled / security locked down env, so i am not able to install python modules such as scapy... so i am having to rely on what i am able to code with the default python 3.5 package. any ideas would be great.

Comment: Not an easy problem, and I am personally not aware of a library that ,might solve it. Most such "client fingerprinting" relies of arcane knowledge about the differences between TCP/IP stacks and subtle differences between their responses to particular probes. You might do some reading around the `nmap` utility to get an idea of what's possible, but aggressive client fingerprinting isn't a simple or a common task.

Answer (score 0):

os.getenv('remoteserver') does not use the variable remoteserver as an argument. Instead it uses a string 'remoteserver'.

Also, are you trying to take input as a command line argument? Or are you trying to take it as user input? Your problem description and implementation differ here. The easiest way would be to run your script using

```
python GetHostID.py
```

and then in your code include

```
remoteServer = raw_input().strip().split()
```

to get the input you want for remoteserver.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

for

```
$python GetHostID.py serverName.com
```

`sys.argv` would be

```
['GetHostID.py', 'serverName.com']
```

but for being friendly to the user have a look at the [argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, `input` reads text *and evaluates it as a Python expression in the current context*.  This is almost never what you want; you want `raw_input` instead.  However, in Python 3, `input` does what `raw_input` did in version 2, and `raw_input` is not available.

So, if you need your code to work in *both* Python 2 and 3, you should do something like this after your imports block:

```
# Apply Python 3 semantics to input() if running under v2.
try:
    input = raw_input
    def raw_input(*a, **k):
        raise NameError('use input()')
except NameError:
    pass
```

This has no effect in Python 3, but in v2 it replaces the stock `input` with `raw_input`, and `raw_input` with a function that always throws an exception (so you notice if you accidentally use `raw_input`).

If you find yourself needing to smooth over *lots* of differences between v2 and v3, the [python-future](http://python-future.org/) library will probably make your life easier.